# undefined reference to 'display'

Tags: c

Is this some kind of linking error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main( )
{

    int num[ ] = { 24, 34, 12, 44, 56, 17 } ;
    dislpay ( &num[0], 6 ) ;
}

display ( int *j, int n )
{

    int i ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= n - 1 ; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "\nelement = %d", *j ) ;
        j++ ;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the spelling bro

Comment: You need to declare the function before you use it, or move the function display to before main. A nice compiler might make it work anyway though if you fix the typo.

Comment: No prototype of `display` ?

Comment: 1------9 spelling error. 2) declare using prototypes before usage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `display` method *before* the main method. In C, functions can only "see" methods that were defined before them OR functions that have prototypes or were defined in the header file.

Sample prototype:

```
void display(int *j, int n);
//...
```

Also, you misspelled `display`:

```
dislpay ( &num[0], 6 ) ;
// ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling

```
dislpay( &num[0], 6 ) ;
   ^^
```

And, do declare the function outside `main()` before using it

```
void display (int*, int) ;
```